# Rename Redis RDB snapshot file without causing disruption

Tags: redis

Our Redis configuration uses RDB for persistence, the snapshot is saved on a regular interval.

The configuration file `/etc/redis.conf` is as below.

```
databases 16
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename "dump.rdb"
dir "/var/lib/redis"
```

Now, we want to change the location and name of the persisted RDB file. But, we want to do this without having to restart Redis, or impacting the current connections to the Redis server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `config set dbfilename xxx` and `config set dir xxx` to modify db directory and filename dynamically.

NOTE: in order to save the change, you need to call `config rewrite`

Comment: Thank you @for_stack. The thing with `config rewrite` was it will only write basic information. We want to retain the existing config file contents but only change the dbfilename and dir. If the config file is updated outside of Redis, will a Redis restart be happy about the same.  
  
Here are the steps,  
- Create the new folder, outside of Redis, setting the ownership as 'redis'.  
- Use the `config set` directives to set the new dbfilename and directory location.  
- Use `sed` to update the Redis config file.

Comment: Once you call `config set` to update dbfilename and dir, Redis will dump RDB file to the new directory with new name (the old rdb file will be kept untouched). `config rewrite` will automatically update redis configuration file, you don't need to manually update it with `sed`.

Comment: Thanks @for_stack. But, will `config rewrite` only update the two values - without touching any other parts of the config.

Comment: If you didn't call config set to update other configs, config rewrite only update these two values.